problem in getting user email in django app with sicial auth
hello i have a django e commerce app that have google social auth when new users create an account we create a some % of dicount code for them i have UserIdentifier class that when users create new account i save either their phoen number or their email address to then when a new users create account i check if we have this users before or not to stop them from abusing the discount code i have this pipeline :
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, login
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import Profile,UserIdentifier
import re

User = get_user_model()

def save_profile(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == 'google-oauth2':
        email = response.get('email')
        first_name = response.get('given_name')
        last_name = response.get('family_name')
        unique_identifier =  email
        user_exists_before = UserIdentifier.objects.filter(identifier=unique_identifier).exists()
        if not user_exists_before:
            UserIdentifier.objects.create(identifier=unique_identifier)
        # Update user fields
        if email:
            user.email = email

        if user.phone_number and not re.match(r'^\d{11}$', user.phone_number):
            user.phone_number = None

        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.save()

        # Update or create profile
        profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        profile.first_name = first_name
        profile.last_name = last_name
        profile.email = email
        profile.save()

        # Handle login and redirection
        request = kwargs.get('request')  # Get the request object from kwargs
        if request:
            user.backend = 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2'
            login(request, user)  # Log the user in regardless of whether they're new

        if user.is_new and not user_exists_before:
            user.is_new = False  # Mark the user as no longer new
            user.save()
            return redirect("accounts:welcome")

        elif user.is_new and user_exists_before:
            user.is_new = False
            user.save()

        # Redirect for existing users
        return redirect("pages:index")

and this is my Customuser model :
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone_number, password=None, **extra_fields):
        email = extra_fields.get('email')

        if email:
            try:
                existing_user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
                return existing_user
            except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
                pass

        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('The Phone Number must be set')
        user = self.model(phone_number=phone_number, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        return self.create_user(phone_number, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_new = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        is_new_user = self.pk is None
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if is_new_user:
            self.generate_referral_code()
            identifier = self.phone_number if self.phone_number else self.email
            print(identifier)
            if not UserIdentifier.objects.filter(identifier=identifier).exists():
                DiscountCodes.objects.create(user=self)
            Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=self)

that print(identifier) when they log with gmail account return for etc its my email account pouryamohamadi35@gmail.com but it return pouryamohamadi3 in database user account have correct email and also UserIdentifier have correct email where is the problem and how can fix it ?
